# Main item wont stay highlighted when i move to sub item

Tags: javascript

http://riveroflifeoutreach.org/drop_down/~design.html

I need the main menu item to remain highlighted when i hover to the subb item. Can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the "sub item" is not actually a child element of the "parent item" you'll have to introduce some pseudo relationship that you can track so you can maintain the "hover" state of the parent when inside a child or you can make sure that sub-item is actually is a child item of the parent element rather than a sibling.

Comment: I will look at your suggestion.so which one will be the easy way to implement this, thanks

Comment: Having the `UL` a child of the `A` element would probably be easiest.